# Why I have different results from run() method in two classes?

Tags: java, init

First :

```
import acm.graphics.GRect;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class GraphTest extends GraphicsProgram{
public void run(){
    GRect a= new GRect(50, 50);
    add(a,50,50);
}
}
```

> This will show a rectangle on screen.

Second:

```
public class MyProg extends Program{
public void run(){
    MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
    add(canvas);
}
}

import java.awt.event.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class MyCanvas extends GCanvas implements ComponentListener{
private GRect rect;
private static final double BOX_WIDTH = 50;
private static final double BOX_HEIGHT= 50;
public MyCanvas(){
    addComponentListener(this);
    rect = new GRect(BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT);
    rect.setFilled(false);
    add(rect,10,10);
}
public void update(){
    GRect rect2 = new GRect(0.1*getWidth(), 0.1*getHeight());
    add(rect2,(getWidth()-BOX_WIDTH)/2,(getHeight()-BOX_HEIGHT)/2);
}
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){update();}
public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e){}
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e){}
public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e){}
}
```

> This is supposed to show me a rectangle, but it doesn't. If I use `init()` then actually 2 rectangles(`rect`and `rect2`) shows.

Anyone can use this example to help me understanding the use of `run()` and `init()` and why I have different results when I'm using `run()`?